# Move row to new tab after sheet updates automatically

Tags: google-apps-script, google-sheets

I need to move rows from a tab based on a cell including "lep". The problem is that it doesn't read the info already on the sheet when it's opened (since it is a sheet that automatically updates new sales from Shopify via Zapier).

What would be the solution for this? I tried onEdit & onOpen already and neither work.

```
function onOpen(e) {
  // assumes source data in sheet named SHOPIFY
  // target sheet of move to named ORG
  // test column with yes is col 17 or Q
  var ss = SpreadsheetApp.getActiveSpreadsheet();
  var s = e.source.getActiveSheet();
  var r = e.source.getActiveRange();

  if(s.getName() == "SHOPIFY" && r.getColumn() == 17 && r.getValue().includes("lep")) {
    var row = r.getRow();
    var numColumns = s.getLastColumn();
    var targetSheet = ss.getSheetByName("ORG");
    var target = targetSheet.getRange(targetSheet.getLastRow() + 1, 1);
    s.getRange(row, 1, 1, numColumns).moveTo(target);
    s.deleteRow(row);
  }
}
```

Answer (score 2, accepted):

```
function moveRows() {
  const ss = SpreadsheetApp.getActive();
  const sh = ss.getSheetByName('SHOPIFY');
  const tsh = ss.getSheetByName('ORG')
  const vs = sh.getDataRange().getValues();//you may wish to change the range to not include headers
  let d=0;
  vs.forEach((r,i)=>{
    if(r[16].toString().includes("lep")) {
      tsh.appendRow(r);
      sh.deleteRow(i+1-d++);
    }
  });
}

function onMyOpen() {
  //needs installable trigger
  moveRows();
}
```

Answer (score 2):

An `onEdit()` [simple trigger](https://developers.google.com/apps-script/guides/triggers) will only run when the user *hand edits* the spreadsheet.

An `onOpen()` simple trigger will only run when you open the spreadsheet *in a web browser*, and its event object does not include information about any recent changes in the spreadsheet.

To detect changes made by Zapier you will need an `on change` [installable trigger](https://developers.google.com/apps-script/guides/triggers/installable). See the [moveRowsFromSpreadsheetToSpreadsheet_](https://support.google.com/docs/thread/39992635?msgid=40432488) script for an example of how to do that.